# Python function as a variable - different number of arguments

Tags: python

Maybe a weird question. Say I have code like this:

```
def foo():
  print "Foo"

def bar(x):
  print x

func = foo
func()
func = bar
arg = 'a'
func(arg)
```

is there a way to have an "empty" argument, so that I can call assign foo() to func and then still call `func(arg)`?

Not just a workaround like

```
if arg is None:
   func()
else:
   func(arg)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, if you use tuples/lists and [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
def foo():
  print "Foo"

def bar(x):
  print x

args = ()
func = foo
func(*args)

func = bar
args = ('a',)
func(*args)
```

Result:

```
Foo
a
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the splat operator

```
args = []
func = foo
func(*args)
func = bar
args = ["Hello world!"]
func(*args)
```

> "Hello World!"

You can even use dictionaries to do this sort of thing

```
funcs = (foo, bar)
func_dict = {func.__name__: func for func in funcs}
args = []
func_dict["foo"](*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def foo(arg=None):
    print "Foo"
```

or use this

```
def foo(*arg):
    print "foo"
```

then you may call it how ever you want

```
arg = 'a'
func = foo
func(arg)
func = bar
func(arg)
```

or as others have pointed out use

```
arg=()
func=foo
func(*arg)
arg=('hello',)
func(*arg)
```